# ImportError: cannot import name 'SIZE'

Tags: python-3.x

День добрый.

Пробую осваивать библиотеку shapely в Python 3. Из мануала взял пример кода.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from figures import SIZE, set_limits, plot_coords, plot_bounds, plot_line_issimple
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку: ImportError: cannot import name 'SIZE'.
Что с этим делать, подскажите

Comment: Создать в модуле figures что-нибудь по имени SIZE.

Comment: Дак в коде же есть строка которая содержит строку:                                                              
    fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=SIZE, dpi=90)

Comment: И что по-вашему делает эта строка и как она должна помочь при импорте?

Comment: Эникейщик, намек Ваш понял. Разобрался. Спасибо большое. Непонятно только почему файла figures.py нету. Пришлось его скачать и положить в папку с проектом.

Comment: Отлично!  Кстати, вы там импортируете пару функций, которые потом переопределяете. Обратите внимание.

Comment: С этим делом тоже разобрался. Еще раз благодарю. Помощь "возьми удочку" лучше все таки чем "возьми рыбу" )))